# Postgres full text search using pg_search - includes(:child_model) breaks the SQL with 'missing FROM-clause entry for table 'child_model'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, left-join, pg-search

I'm using postgres full text search with the pg_search gem. The search itself is working well, but I need to further filter the results and here are the details:

```rb
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :invites

 def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
   search(query)
  else
   scoped
  end

end
```

Notebooks Controller:

```rb
def index
 if params[:query].present?
  @notebooks = Notebook.text_search(params[:query]).includes(:invites).where("invites.email = :email OR notebooks.access = :access OR notebooks.access = :caccess OR notebooks.user_id = :uid", email: current_user.email, access: "open", caccess: "closed", uid: current_user.id)
 else
  @notebooks = Notebook.includes(:invites).where("invites.email = :email OR notebooks.access = :access OR notebooks.access = :caccess OR notebooks.user_id = :uid", email: current_user.email, access: "open", caccess: "closed", uid: current_user.id)
 end
```

The error I get is 'missing FROM-clause entry for table 'invites'. I have tried many different things including:

1. replacing 'includes' with 'joins'
2. replacing 'includes(:invites) with joins('LEFT JOIN "invites" ON "invites"."email" = "email" ')
3. changing the order of the .text_search and the .includes calls.
4. adding the includes call in the controller, in the model, in a scope, and in the text_search function definition.

I keep getting the same error, and when using the joins call with SQL it does not filter by invite emails, and shows multiple repeats of each search result.

I would just remove the include(:invites) because the text_search itself is working just fine. But I really need this condition to be included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I'm just getting my SQL call wrong, but I also would like to understand why the .includes(:invites) works without the pg text_search but won't work with it.

**Edit #1 - more specific question**

I think there are 2 slightly different questions here. The first seems to be some issue with combining pg_search gem and an 'includes(:invites)' call. The second question is what is the equivalent SQL statement that I can use in order to avoid making the 'includes(:invites)' call. I think it should be a LEFT JOIN of some sort, but I don't think I'm making it correctly. In my db, a Notebook has_many invites, and invites have an attribute 'email'. I need the the notebooks with invites that have an email equal to the current_user's email.

Help with either of these would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link that showed me the solution to my problem:
https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/109

Here is my specific code:

```js
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :invites

 include PgSearch
 pg_search_scope :search, against: [:title],
  using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "english"}},
  associated_against: {user: :name, notes:[:title, :content]}

 scope :with_invites_and_access, lambda{ |c_user_email|
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN invites ON invites.notebook_id = notebooks.id').where('invites.email = ? OR notebooks.access = ? OR notebooks.access = ?', c_user_email, 'open', 'closed')
 }

 def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
   search(query).with_invites_and_access(current_user_email)
  else
   scoped
  end
 end
end
```

The key was the joins statement. joins(:invites) doesn't work, includes(:invites) doesn't work. The full SQL statement is required:

```
joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN invites ON invites.notebook_id = notebooks.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a join but I cannot see what makes joined **invites** fields to appear in the SELECT statement.
I think You may need to add the fields from the **invites** table into select() like this

```
  select('invites.*').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN invites ON invites.notebook_id = notebooks.id').where('invites.email = ? OR notebooks.access = ? OR notebooks.access = ?', c_user_email, 'open', 'closed')
 }
```